# reverse .label in swift

Tags: swift, colors, label, ios-darkmode

I want my text to appear `.white` when in normal mode and `.black` when in dark mode. How do I do that? `.label` only makes the text `.black` in normal and `.white` in dark mode but I want it the other way around.

Anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: Just create a custom Color Set or use `systemBackground` color

Answer (score 3):

`let myLabelColor = UIColor(dynamicProvider: { $0.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .black : .white })`

---

Since iOS 13, `UIColor` has an `init(dynamicProvider:)`

> Creates a color object that uses the specified block to generate its color data dynamically.
>  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238041-init

If you will be creating a lot of dynamic colors, you might want to make a convenience init—that saves you the typing, and your intention is more clear to the reader:

```
extension UIColor {

    /// Creates a color object that responds to `userInterfaceStyle` trait changes.
    public convenience init(light: UIColor, dark: UIColor) {
      guard #available(iOS 13.0, *) else { self.init(cgColor: light.cgColor); return }
      self.init(dynamicProvider: { $0.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? dark : light })
    }

}
```

Usage: `let myLabelColor = UIColor(light: .white, dark: .black)`

---

(Note that you can use any other trait from the provided trait collection. For example, you could return a different color if the size class changes)

Answer (score 0):

In my assets I created a new "Color Set". For chose white for "Any Appearance" and black for "Dark". Then I gave this Image Set a name and called it like so:

```
text.textColor = UIColor(named: "ImageSet1")
```